# Table Valued Function vs Scalar Values Function for single return Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am returning single value from a scaler function as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNoOfAssignedCases]
(
    @UserID INT,
    @FromD DATETIME,
    @ToD DATETIME
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CaseCount INT = 0
    SELECT @CaseCount = COUNT(1) FROM Cases
    WHERE 
        CaseAssignedToAssessor = @UserID AND 
        CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) >= @FromD AND
        CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) <= @ToD
    RETURN @CaseCount
END
```

And using it as below:

```
SELECT [Name], [DBO].[GetNoOfAssignedCases](UserID, GETDATE()-30, GETDATE()) FROM Users
```

Can it be replace with table valued function? **And will it have any performance impact? Which will be faster?**

Comment: You just edited you question and ask about performance: It depends... If you have to get a counter for all Users in one go, the fastest might be an old fashioned `GROUP BY`... The Inline-UDF with `APPLY` should be quite the same as a `JOIN` with a sub-select. This is surely faster than a scalar calculation for many rows or a multi-statement UDF. How many rows are there (in `Users` and `Cases`)?

Comment: On more hint: Asking about performance you should read about "sargable expressions". Your `CAST(ActionDateTime...)` will not be sargable...

Comment: @Shnugo there will be more than 100 users and more than 20,000 of cases. And I am using 3 other functions like this for getting count based on different criteria on one select. So I don't think i can use group by.

Comment: If there is an index on your foreign key in `Cases` (and in other tables), a simple count will - for sure! - never cause performance problems. An inline UDF - as stated in my answer - is roughly the same as a JOIN on a sub-select and - if done for many Users at once - is much better than a row-by-row approach.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious: Could you solve your question? Which approach did you choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My discussion with Jonatha Dickinson (look at his answer) brought me to do some quick tests:

It comes out, that the *pure,embedded scalar sub-select* is not that bad. Querying *just one value it's even the fastest*. As expected the Scalar Function is bad. The more fields are given back by the TVF the better is the relativ performance gain.

The only sure answer is: *The scalar function  is the worst* and a multi-line TVF is - most of the time - slower than inline. **Any ad-hoc approach tends to be faster**.

But I could set up special cases to all situations (except the scalar function), where one approach was the fastest.

Conclusion: (as always :-)   ) It depends...

Hint: Best is to let this go against a big database with many tables and columns.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountColumnScalar(@TableSchema AS VARCHAR(100),@TableName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName);
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountConstraintScalar(@TableSchema AS VARCHAR(100),@TableName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName);
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountAllTVF(@TableSchema AS VARCHAR(100),@TableName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME) AS ColCounter
             ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME) AS ConstraintCounter    ;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountAllTVF_multiline(@TableSchema AS VARCHAR(100),@TableName AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (ColCounter INT,ConstraintCounter INT)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME) AS ColCounter
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME) AS ConstraintCounter;
RETURN;
END
GO

DECLARE @time DATETIME=GETDATE();
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
     ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME ) AS ColCounter
     ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME ) AS ConstraintCounter
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t;
PRINT 'pure embedded scalar sub-select: ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-@time AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(MAX)); SET @time=GETDATE();


SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
     ,dbo.CountColumnScalar(t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME ) AS ColCounter 
     ,dbo.CountConstraintScalar(t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME ) AS ConstraintCount 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
PRINT 'scalar function: ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-@time AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(MAX)); SET @time=GETDATE();


SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME
      ,colJoin.ColCount
      ,conJoin.ConstraintCount 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) As ColCount,c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c 
            GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME) AS colJoin ON  colJoin.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND colJoin.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) As ConstraintCount,c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS c 
            GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.TABLE_NAME) AS conJoin ON  conJoin.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND conJoin.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
PRINT 'JOINs on sub-selects: ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-@time AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(MAX)); SET @time=GETDATE();

SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME
      ,ColCounter.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.CountAllTVF(t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME) AS ColCounter
PRINT 'TVF inline: ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-@time AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(MAX)); SET @time=GETDATE();


SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME
      ,ColCounter.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.CountAllTVF_multiline(t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME) AS ColCounter
PRINT 'TVF multiline: ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-@time AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(MAX)); SET @time=GETDATE();
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.CountColumnScalar;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CountAllTVF;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CountAllTVF_multiline;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CountConstraintScalar;
```

Comment: Which is fatser? In-line TVF or Multi-line TVF?

Comment: This is one of the few sure answers: inline is faster.

Comment: @dotNetAddict, your SqlFiddle is a completely new question... Please do not ask follow-up questions in comments. Rather place a new question and - if you want - place a link within a comment if you think a certain user would most likely give you a good answer. If you do so, I'll answer there in detail, just in short: What you've put in your fiddle is not at all a TVF!, This is a function to concatenate words, returning a single string. This is best to be done inlining with a CTE. Place a new question and set me a link. I'll answer there quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could so something like this (untested)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNoOfAssignedCases]
(
    @UserID INT,
    @FromD DATETIME,
    @ToD DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS CaseCount 
    FROM Cases
    WHERE 
        CaseAssignedToAssessor = @UserID AND 
        CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) >= @FromD AND
        CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) <= @ToD;
GO


--And a call like this
SELECT [Name],CaseCounter.CaseCount
FROM Users
OUTER APPLY [DBO].[GetNoOfAssignedCases](UserID, GETDATE()-30, GETDATE()) AS CaseCounter
```

But - if you really need nothing more than a scalar value! - I don't know why...

Reasons why a TVF is a good idea:

- You want to get the "scalar" value for many rows in one go
- You want - maybe later - get more values out of this function

Answer (score 2):

> will it have any performance impact?

Yes. We use functions quite extensively. While optimizing a specific query I found that SQL optimizes scalar-valued functions as a separate entity, where TVFs are "inlined" into the main query and then optimized as a whole. Exceptions to this may exist but we have found that TVFs are universally faster (only slightly slower than inlining the function yourself).

> Can it be replace with table valued function?

Yes. If it's performance you are worried about this is the format that you should use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNoOfAssignedCases]
(
    @UserID INT,
    @FromD DATETIME,
    @ToD DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS Count FROM Cases
    WHERE 
        CaseAssignedToAssessor = @UserID AND 
        CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) >= @FromD AND
        CAST(ActionDateTime AS DATE) <= @ToD;
```

Cross apply can then be used to execute the function:

```
SELECT [Name], [AC].[Count] FROM Users
    CROSS APPLY [DBO].[GetNoOfAssignedCases](UserID, GETDATE()-30, GETDATE()) AS [AC]
```

You need to `RETURN SELECT` for the "inlining" to occur. In addition, it is your job to ensure that these functions don't return more than one record (unless you actually want the `CROSS APPLY` behavior - which you almost never do).

Comment: Why are you repeating my answer? The only new information of your answer is the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` which **might** increase the performance a little. This would depend on many circumstances we don't know. Wouldn't it have been enough to state this as a comment to an existing answer? And btw: Using `CROSS APPLY` will surpess users with no case at all... And why should a function **never** return more than one record? This `COUNT`won't anyway, but why **never**?

Comment: @Shnugo it answers the whole question. You didn't touch on performance at all, which was explicitly queried. "circumstances we don't know", no that's documented behavior. A scalar TVF should not return more than one record as `CROSS APPLY` is the Cartesian product: resulting in more than one row. Interesting, the asker has even bolded the performance query.

Comment: Well, you cannot know, that my answer was there **before** the OP added the performance question via edit. I gave some answers directly in comments. You speak about a "scalar TVF" - whatever this is... Yes, one could misuse a TVF to deliver just a scalar value - but why should one? `CROSS APPLY` will not return users with no case at all. Better think about `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: @Shnugo "but why should one?" The first part of my question answered that: performance. That is *precisely* why RLS uses that bare (scalar) form of TVFs.

Comment: Really? If you want to get the CaseCount for several 1000 users you should - that's exactly what both of us answered, use an inline(!) TVF rather than a scalar function. But this is not a "scalar TVF", just a table with only one column... Well, to be honest, Both of us have quite the same in mind... Let's stop this silly quarrel, happy coding!

Comment: @Shnugo Copy the performance implications over to your answer and I'll remove mine - the performance difference is substantial in some situations (20s query down to 30ms).

Comment: No, it was a little childish from my side to argue around, that's SO :-)  Your answer is correct and therefore helpful, You've got an up-vote, just keep it there...

Comment: I did some research:  If I understand this correctly (at least it's by Sommarskog...) there might be no effect in inline TVFs if you use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92dbc7c4-a2a9-4c32-a728-9fe85970b9c4/with-schemabinding-in-function

Comment: @Shnugo thanks! Updated the answer and removed that false information.

Comment: Hi, I did some tests and added a new answer. This might be interesting for you. It is actually not that easy to predict, which approach is the fastest. In simple processes the optimizer is - obviously - doing a very good job..

Answer (score 0):

Table Valued Function will go like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GETNOOFASSIGNEDCASES] (@UserID INT,
                                              @FromD  DATETIME,
                                              @ToD    DATETIME)
RETURNS @CaseCount TABLE (
  cnt INT NULL )
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @CaseCount
                  (cnt)
      SELECT Count(1)
      FROM   Cases
      WHERE  CaseAssignedToAssessor = @UserID
             AND Cast(ActionDateTime AS DATE) >= @FromD
             AND Cast(ActionDateTime AS DATE) <= @ToD
  END
```

You should invoke the above defined table valued function using cross apply or outer apply:

```
SELECT [Name],tmp.cnt
FROM   Users
       CROSS apply [DBO].[GETNOOFASSIGNEDCASES](UserID, Getdate() - 30, Getdate()) as tmp
```

Comment: In such a case one should **always** prefer the ad-hoc (or inline) UDF! And be aware of Users without a case. Better use `OUTER APPLY`...